# ExecuteReader requires an open connection -- thing it is *already open*, why is this happening?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

The code below has been used successfully in other parts of the application without fault.

However, for some reason, an InvalidOperationException is thrown when it comes time to read data from the Access database.

The code below contains only the essentials (not the items that are trying to be read, as that would made readability difficult).

Why am I getting this error, despite the fact I am calling the "Open" method on my connection?

Code follows:

```
string connString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source= C:\\temp\\IntelliMed.accdb";
        string queryString = "SELECT patientID, firstName, lastName, patientGender, dateOfBirth, residentialAddress, postalAddress, nationalHealthNumber, telephoneNumber, cellphoneNumber, cscNumber FROM PatientRecord WHERE patientID = @patientID";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.CommandText = queryString;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", patientID);
                command.Connection = ctnPatientRecord;

                OleDbDataReader prescriptionDetailsReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (prescriptionDetailsReader.Read())
                {
                  //Read stuff.
                }
                //Close the reader.
               }
               //Close the connection.
             } //Method "closing" bracket.
```

Any help is gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting the connection of the command to a new value after calling con.Open(). Is that connection open too?

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure, now that you mention it. I'll get back to you on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should associate the command with the connection

```
command.Connection = con;
```

or better yet create the command through the connection using the [CreateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of the constructor.

Comment: Hi Stilgar, I just need to check something, then I will let you know if using your solution worked.

Comment: Hi Stilgar, I am not sure how to implement your suggestion. Could you provide some code, please?

Comment: Just add the line in my answer after the line where you create the command

Comment: Thanks. Then, I just need to do "con.Open", right? (no quotes, obviously).